# What should I do when I'm not able to connect to the server through anything?

Tags: server, ssh, ftp, putty, filezilla

Today surprisingly my server got damaged. My website will be open as well but I cannot connect to the server neither through **PuTTY** nor **FileZilla**.

When I write the username into PuTTY and press <kbd>enter</kbd>, it quickly kicks me out:

[image]

FTP protocol doesn't work either:

[image]

Also I cannot see databases through *phpmyadmin* either. But I my website is ok I all its pages will be load as well.

Is there any idea how can I connect to the server in this situation?

Comment: do you have physical access to the server?

Comment: @Yaron . . . not really

Comment: Well "ftp" won't work if ssh is not working since you're using sftp ;-).. So the website is working but ssh is not working anymore, is that correct?

Comment: You probably set something wrong in your startup scripts.

Comment: Seems to me you need someone WITH physical access to inspect the server; perhaps to restart sshd.